# trying to get a two bash functions with piping and optional args working

Tags: bash, zsh, zsh-alias

I have two things, one is a function the other is an alias and they don't quite work right.

The first is for tailing logs but only showing the first 3 lines by finding the important part of the log you're looking for and then showing the next two lines or however many you specify.

```
# tail -f $1 | grep $2 -A 2
function tinput() {
    if [ "$3" != "" ]
    then
        $(tail -f $1 | grep $2 -A $3)
    else
        $(tail -f $1 | grep $2 -A 2)
    fi
}
```

Lets say I use it like this:

```
tinput /var/log/webapps/app.name.com.error.log,#<.*Error:
```

It errors like this:

```
zsh: no such file or directory: .*Error:
```

I'm not sure but maybe it's not seeing the args properly or becuase I'm doing piping?

The second is:

```
function loadmysqldump() {
  $(pv $1 | mysql -u root $1)
}
```

It's for making mysql db dump recovery status a little more obvious (why programs don't use somthing to show that it's working I don't know, even a  spinner would be nice) but not as obnoxious as doing `-v`.

Ok, so I admit to making a booboo, for some reason I forgot that args in the terminal are delimited by spaces, not apostrophes, so it does work; frankly I'm only using grep becuase I can't get what I actually want, the first n lines of each individual output from `tail -f` and nothing else I tried worked.

Comment: not sure about zsh, but in bash, you can't use variables in aliases.. use function instead.. see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30925/in-bash-when-to-alias-when-to-script-and-when-to-write-a-function/30964#30964

Comment: You are executing the output of the piped command line `tail -f $1 | grep $2 -A 2`. Why do you use `$( ... )`?

Comment: In your first function, as a way of debugging it, add `echo "1:$1, 2:$2, 3:$3"` to the start of it. Then call it again and see what you positional parameters are.

Comment: @Jdamian Becuase accourding to [this](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/176721-pipe-grep-doesnt-work-bash-script.html#edit302597688), it's one of the few ways to get piping to grep (or in general I guess) in a function to work.

Comment: Which is apparently not needed, as it works which meant that It was the mistake I made not allowing it work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't (or shouldn't) call it like this:

```
tinput /var/log/webapps/app.name.com.error.log,#<.*Error:
```

The reason has to do with how `zsh` handles patterns that don't match anything. The presence of the unquoted `*` makes the entire first argument a pattern that `zsh` tries to match with existing files. When it doesn't match anything, it raises an error. You can change this behavior by unsetting the `NOMATCH` option, which will make `zsh` act like other shells and treat the pattern literally. A better solution is to be explicit and quote the argument:

```
tinput "/var/log/webapps/app.name.com.error.log,#<.*Error:"
```

In none of the cases above do you need command substitution.

```
function loadmysqldump() {
  pv $1 | mysql -u root $1
}

function tinput() {
    if [ "$3" != "" ]
    then
        tail -f $1 | grep $2 -A $3
    else
        tail -f $1 | grep $2 -A 2
    fi
}
```

You can refactor `tinput` significantly to specify 2 as the default value for the `-A` option if `$3` is empty or unset.

```
function tinput() {
    tail -f $1 | grep $2 -A ${3:-2}
}
```